# stat summary position by other aesthetic parameter in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am preparing descriptive graphs of my data and I ran into a specific problem. For each boxplot I show the number of observations (don't ask me why, so they just want it =D). If I use only two parameters in ggplot, there is not a problem. However, when I add the aesthetic color parameter for gender to the graph. The text starts to overlap or is just possitioned between boxplot. It looks to me that it is necessarily to add new parametr to the functions (begining of code) which created automatic position of the stat summary text. These new parametr would be able to move the text on the x-axis to the left or to the right, depending on the colour aesthetic category. But not sure how to do it

```
# data
df <- data_frame(id = c(1:50),
                 sex = sample(1:2, 50, replace=T),
                 age = sample(18:50, 50, replace=T),
                 state = sample(state.name[1:4], 50, replace=T))

# auto positioning function
give.n <- function(x){
  return(c(y = median(x)*1.05, label = length(x))) 
  # experiment with the multiplier to find the perfect position
}

# plot
ggplot(df, aes(x= as.factor(state), y = age, color = as.factor(sex))) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(fun.data = give.n, geom = "text", fun.y = median)
```

[plot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T15yy.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be fixed using the `position` argument, i.e. add `position = position_dodge(width = .75)`to `stat_summmary`:

```r
# data
set.seed(42)

df <- data.frame(id = c(1:50),
                 sex = sample(1:2, 50, replace=T),
                 age = sample(18:50, 50, replace=T),
                 state = sample(state.name[1:4], 50, replace=T))

# auto positioning function
give.n <- function(x){
  return(c(y = median(x)*1.05, label = length(x))) 
  # experiment with the multiplier to find the perfect position
}

library(ggplot2)

# plot
ggplot(df, aes(x= as.factor(state), y = age, color = as.factor(sex))) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(fun.data = give.n, geom = "text", fun.y = median, position = position_dodge(width = .75))
#> Warning: `fun.y` is deprecated. Use `fun` instead.
```

[image]

Comment: Ty @stefan, and of course! I still thinking about some complicated solution and forgot to position argument (facepalm)

Comment: ((: This happens sometimes. (;